# How do I check my level password in Geometry Dash?

Tags: geometry-dash

So, on some geometry dash levels people's description say, "Pass: 6473" which allows you to copy their level! How do I find my level password? Please help!

Comment: You just can't; if you've forgotten it - The only way is to bruteforce it. | Unless there's an external program that can do it for you...

Answer (score 1):

If you still have the original level saved in your levels, there is a way to retrieve your password.

You need to re-verify the level. Just make a change that is inconsequential from the source level, and re-verify the level. The level's information should have changed from "Uploaded" to "Verified". Then you can click Publish, and check the password from there.

If you do not possess the original source level, then I'm afraid it's not currently possible to check your password.